# Is there a way to replace a generated endpoint in Postgraphile?

Tags: postgraphile

I have a Postgraphile-using database with a `foo` table.  Recently I moved the columns of that table into a `bar` table.

In other words, before I had:

```
Foos:
{ id: 1, title: 'Bob' }
```

But now I have:

```
Foos:
{ id: 1, bar_id: 2 }

Bars:
{ id: 2, title: 'Bob' }
```

In postgraphile, this means my queries have changed from:

```
foo { title }
```

to:

```
foo { bar { title } }
```

I'd like to somehow replace the `foo` endpoint in my API, so that I can once again allow queries like:

```
foo { title }
```

How can I do this?

If I try to use the `makeExtendSchemaPlugin` and define my own `foo` endpoint, I get an error saying that I have two definitions for the same `foo` endpoint.

Is there some way to make new endpoint "trump" the generated one, either by using that plugin, or by using a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to make new endpoint "trump" the generated one?

No. You cannot have two plugins/hooks generate the same field, it will always throw an error. There is no way to make one "overwrite" the other.

What you can do is

- [`@omit`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/smart-tags/#omit) the generated field
- [re-`@name`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/smart-tags/#name) the generated field
- add back a [computed `Foo.title` field](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/computed-columns/) instead of adding a completely new `Foo` type with its own `Query.foo` field